# Embedding forms - cart system

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to create a basic cart system using `symfony2`

I have the following Entities:

```
Product
Cart
CartItem
```

I can create the cart and add the products as cartItems, but I'm a little unsure of how to display them in terms of the actual cart, i.e. a Cart, with the CartItems in terms of a form.

Am I right in thinking I'd need to embed them into the CartType form?

Comment: you should create a CartType holding a collection of CartItemTypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a form collection is the correct solution for your need
You can follow this doc: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html